# Scatter plot with factor on horizontal axis

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to produce a simple scatter plot with a factor on the x-axis.  The resulting plot shows horizontal lines rather than dots (can't upload the image, unfortunately).

Transcribing some SAS code to R based on example 3.5 from *An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models* by Dobson, Bennett, per my professor's request.  Purpose is to introduce my classmates to R, so I am trying to keep this as simple and clean as possible.

```
dat <- data.frame(age_group = c("30-34", "35-39", "40-44", 
    "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69"), 
                  deaths = c(1, 5, 5, 12, 25, 38, 54, 65), 
                  population = c(17742, 16554, 16059, 13083, 10784, 9645, 10706, 9933))
dat <- within(dat, {
              rate <- deaths / population * 100000
              lograte <- log(deaths / population * 100000)
              })
```

And my plot

```
with(dat, plot(age_group, lograte, pch=19))
```

does not produce the 'dots' that I would like.  I have a hacked together solution which I'll post later, but wanted to see if there was a better way.  Again, apologies that I can't upload the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using base R you can do it as follows:
Surpress the x-axis by `xaxt="n"` and add it afterwards manually.

```
plot(1:nrow(dat), dat$lograte, xaxt="n", xlab="age_group", ylab="lograte", pch=19)
axis(1, at=1:8, labels=dat$age_group)
```

[image]

You can achieve it using `ggplot2` instead of the base R plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=age_group, y=lograte)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  I would prefer base R if possible, but this is a nice solution.

Comment: @Floo0: you were quicker than me. I'll leave my answer for the explanation of why Sam's code produced the unexpected  result.

Answer (score 5):

`plot` is a generic function in R, which means that depending on the class of its first argument, different functions may be called. Since your first argument is a factor, the function that is called is `plot.factor`. From the  documentation of `plot.factor`:

> For numeric y a boxplot is used

So, a box plot is what you get. If you want to avoid this, you can convert `age_group` to numeric:

```
with(dat, plot(as.numeric(age_group), lograte, pch=19))
```

This will probably not generate the axis you want, because the labels simply run from 1 to 8. You can produce a plot without x-axis and then add the axis with a second command:

```
with(dat, plot(as.numeric(age_group), lograte, pch=19, xaxt = "n", xlab = "age group"))
axis(1, 1:8, dat$age_group)
```

I have also added an axis label. This gives the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the plot and explanation about `plot.factor`.  This is very helpful.