# X-axis as the state names and Y-axis as data points in R Shiny

Tags: r, plot

I'm working on R-shiny web page. In that i want to plot scatter plot x vs y , X as the state names and y as the data points . In that it shows the horizontal lines instead of points. How to solve this problem ?  [I want scatter plot instead of horizontal lines , i don't understand why it shows this kind of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8cqc.png)Thank you in advance.

```
ui.R
    library(shiny)

    shinyUI(fluidPage(  titlePanel("Multivariable plot"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label = h3("Select CSV File")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'col names', value = TRUE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Seperator', choices = c("comma"=',',"semi comma"=';'), selected = ','),

      #checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h3("Wybierz Kolumny"), choices = NULL),
      # there is combobox to pick column
      selectInput("combobox", label = h3("x var"),choices = NULL),
     #selectInput("combobox1", label = h3("y var"),choices = NULL)
     selectizeInput("combobox1", label = h3("y var"), choices = NULL ,multiple = TRUE )

    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))

Server.R
    library(ggplot2)

function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header )

    #updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    # this line updates selection in combobox 
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "combobox1", choices = colnames(dataSet), server = TRUE)
    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()    
  })

  output$multivarplot <- reactivePlot(function(){ 
   x    <- data()[, input$combobox]
    ydat    <- data.frame(data()[, input$combobox1])

     xval<-data.frame(x,ydat)
  #  ggplot(xval, aes(x = reorder(x, -x), y = y))+geom_point(colour='red')
   #g= ggplot(xval, aes(x,ydat[,1]))+geom_point(colour='red')

     ny <- ncol(ydat)
    # par(mar = c(3,3, 3, .31))
    # par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,2.1))
     par(mfcol=c(12,12),mfrow=c(1,1))

      #plot(x,ydat[,1],col ='red')
     if(ny==1)
     #   g= ggplot(xval, aes(x,ydat[,1]))+geom_point(colour='red')
     #  g
     # # 
       plot(x,ydat[,1],type = "p")

  else 

    if(ny==2)
    #  { g= ggplot(xval, aes(x,ydat[,1]))+geom_point(colour='red')
    #  r=g+ggplot(xval, aes(x,ydat[,2]))+geom_point(colour='blue')
    #  r
    # }


      { y1 <- ydat[,1]
         y2 <- ydat[,2]
     plot(x, y1, ylim = range(c(y1,y2)),colour='red')
         points(x,y2)}


   # req(is.numeric(x))
    #plot(x,y, col = 'blue', border = 'white')
  })


  output$tb <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),

                  tabPanel("Plot", 
                           plotOutput("multivarplot")))
  })
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you used to make the plot.

Comment: Those are probably boxplots of a single value. That is the default because your `x` variable is a factor. Use `plot.default(x, y)` instead to get a scatterplot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scatter plot with factor on horizontal axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483199/scatter-plot-with-factor-on-horizontal-axis)

Comment: plot.default(x,y) is not showing state names. It shows numbers on x-axis.

Comment: thanks the problem is solved by using above link.